# Can't remotely connect to Python Socket

Tags: python, sockets, networking, server, portforwarding

I have created a chat application using python sockets and Tkinter and it all works perfectly locally however the Client is unable to connect to the server remotely (when I enter my public IP address as the host) I have already fully port-forwarded my network and I know how to port forward very well and when I run an online Port Open scanner that checks if a port is open it states that the port is open!?

I have port-forwarded my router on a number of ports and updating the client and server accordingly however the client and telnet could still not connect..  I have also disabled all my windows firewalls and I disabled all of the routers firewalls.

Here is a very simple socket client and server model which I am trying to troubleshoot my problem using.

Server

```
import socket

s = socket.socket()
host='0.0.0.0'

port = 2000
s.bind((host,port))

s.listen(5)
while True:
    c, addr = s.accept()
    print ("Got a connection from: ", addr)
    c.send(bytes("Thanks for connecting",'utf8'))
    c.close()
```

Client

```
import socket 

s = socket.socket()  
port = 2000    

s.connect(("109.156.114.183", port))
print (s.recv(1024))
s.close
```

Telnet

```
C:\Users\Maks>telnet 109.156.114.183 2000
Connecting To 109.156.114.183...Could not open connection to the host, on port 2000: Connect failed
```

When I try to connect to the server on 127.0.0.1 or localhost or from within my local network the client connects perfectly and telnet can connect as well. I am 200% sure I have port forwarded correctly because when I run a Port Open scan it says that the port(2000) is open.

Please help!
Thanks-
Maks

Comment: If it works within your local network then either the port is not properly forwarded on the router, you are using the wrong IP address as destination or something in between the client and your router (with the forwarded port) is blocking the connection (for example your ISP). *"... when I run a Port Open scan it says that the port(2000) is open."* - that does not necessarily mean that the port is properly forwarded. Try this scan again when the port is not supposed to be open and see what the scan reports.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, here's some images confirming what you've said. Port-forwarding is very simple on my router so I'm not really sure what I could have done wrong here. [link to images](https://imgur.com/a/7HGolE6)

Comment: [Port Open test](http://prntscr.com/ntf75e)

Comment: ISP does not seem to block anything based on this additional information. In this case it might be something blocking the access at the client side, i.e. between the client and the ISP. For example corporate firewalls typically don't allow arbitrary access to the internet but only to selected ports.

Comment: Yes, It's very strange... I'm at home so there's no firewalls running on my network at all. Do you possibly think it's some sort of loopback thing where i'm trying to remotely connect to my network from inside the network itself which is disabled on my router or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm at home so there's no firewalls running on my network at all.

That comment was the missing piece to solve your problem. You actually don't connect from remote as your question implies but you try to connect from inside your local network to the externally visible address of your router.

Such a setup is supported by some routers and not by others. It looks like you router does not support it. For more information on this see [NAT hairpinning (or NAT loopback)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairpinning).

Comment: I think you may be right. I'm asking my friend now to try and connect to the chat server and if they can connect then the problem will be truly solved. Thanks so much, definitely saved me some time if this works for them :)