# How to connect to a socket server in my network?

Tags: python, sockets, networking, server, client

After doing port forwarding on port 50000 on my router now i can connect to my server using a computer from another network :

SERVER CODE :

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET , socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(("0.0.0.0" , 50000))
s.listen(5)

c , a = s.accept()
```

CLIENT CODE (that is connected to another network) :

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET , socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(("my_public_ip" , 50000))
```

but the problem is that if i try to connect from my network to the server that is on my network (after doing port forwarding) i get an error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

Comment: do you have any firewall on the "server" machine that listens on 5000 port? are you trying to reach it on the public IP or the LAN IP?

Comment: Likely your router does not support NAT hairpinning, i.e. you cannot connect to your public IP address from inside the network. For details see [Can't remotely connect to Python Socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56310901/cant-remotely-connect-to-python-socket)

Comment: @ilias-sp i am trying to reach it on the public ip

Comment: @SteffenUllrich yes thanks i've read about that now . is there an option where i can enable it ? or if i cant do hairpinning then does that mean that  my router doesn't suport it and there is no option to enable ?

Comment: @randomdude: There is usually either support or no support, i.e. nothing where it can be enabled or disabled. But you might check the documentation of your unknown router if this is different there.