# Server implementation with python socket and port forwarding

Tags: python, sockets, portforwarding

I've been trying to implement a server-client connection, here is my code-

**Server.py**

```
import socket

server = socket.socket()
server.bind(('', 2112))
server.listen(5)
print('Server created with port 2112')
server.accept()
print('Connected')
```

**Client.py**

```
import socket

##Public_IP is the Public IP address of my router
client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect((Public_IP, 2112))
```

Both Server.py and Client.py are running on my computer(server). It works just fine when I replace Public_IP with '192.168.0.143', but when I use Public_IP, it gives the following error-

```
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

Is it because I'm running both Server.py and Client.py on the same computer? Please let me know what I'm doing wrong.

Setting up port forwarding -

[Public IP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ltHt.png)

[Port forwarding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b61pD.png)

[Private IP address of server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYCtz.png)

I followed this [tutorial](https://youtu.be/2tIUts0fyFk) for setting up port forwarding.

I also tried replacing the empty string in Server.py with my private IP address-

`server.bind(('192.168.0.143', 2112))`

Edit: I have tried-

- Running Client.py externally (on a different LAN) with firewall down on both the ends, but didn't make any difference (it gave a timeout error).
- Running Client.py on the same LAN with firewall down, that seemed to work fine.
- Running the Client.py on the same device also worked fine with the firewall down.

Comment: Likely your router does not support NAT loopback. See [Can't remotely connect to Python Socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56310901/cant-remotely-connect-to-python-socket)

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Finally got the time to try connecting externally with my friend's help, it still didn't work due to timeout error :\

Comment: *"...  try connecting externally ..."* - this is likely a different problem, like missing port forwardings on your friends router or firewall settings.

Comment: I don't understand, do I have to implement port forwarding on the client side as well? But that would mean everyone who wants to connect to the server would have to implement it on their router, right?

Comment: *"I have to implement port forwarding on the client side as well"* -  No. But you might have implemented port forwarding wrongly at the server side. Or the server system might have firewall settings which prevent connections to it.

Comment: Hi Steffen, really appreciate your help. With the firewall down, I still can't connect to devices connected to a different router (on a different LAN?). Turning the firewall off, I was able to connect on the same device though...